# Can't seem to inject angular-jwt into factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, jwt, angularjs-factory

I am trying to inject angular-jwt into a factory for use in auth functions, but I keep getting the error

`Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string

return new ErrorConstructor(message);`

Here's the code:
`webapp.factory('Auth', ['angular-jwt'], function($http, API_URL, $window, $location, jwtHelper ) {`

Also the learning curve to angular seems sharp in this way, how am I supposed to make sense out of the error to find out why it's failing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject all the required dependency in your app module. That what you were injecting new module while declaring factory.

**Code**

```
var webapp = angular.module('myAppName',['angular-jwt']);

webapp.factory('Auth',['$http', 'API_URL', '$window', '$location', 'jwtHelper', 
   function($http, API_URL, $window, $location, jwtHelper ) {
   //your c0de here
}]);
```

Comment: I will accept this answer once stackoverflow lets me since it worked, but can you explain what's happening? I had injected on the module as well. I see examples everywhere that show dependencies declared in brackets on controllers and factories etc (http://goo.gl/yr5aTg) why don't I have to pass this dependency to the factory? Also how does the module's angular-jwt translate to jwtHelper?

Comment: @PixMach that are the various types of dependancy injection..use array annotation dependancy is more prefered where you injected dependency in array first then use them in your controller function

Comment: I think you forgot a ] at the end. I kind of liked the first way you did it before the edit, can you explain what the difference is?

Comment: @PixMach its nothing but the one of the type of dependancy injection, we need to follow this pattern when we are minifying js files